# How to convert Byte array into string?

Tags: arrays, structure

I have structure as follows:

struct data
{int no; string name; int id};

I am converting this structure into bytearray. I need to convert this back into structure format. For that I need to convert first members into integer and string. How to convert bytearray into structure ?

Comment: What language / architecture? A c++ answer and a C#/.NET answer will look very different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class. Here's an example of [how to convert byte array to int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx).

For string conversion `BitConverter` is not really useful (as Marc mentiones in his comment), even though it has the ToChar() method. You can use [`ASCIIEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx), [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) or any of the other XxxEncoding classes in the [`System.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.aspx) namespace instead.

Note, this is .Net specific.

Comment: BitConverter won't help you with strings; and you need to be very careful about endianness (since BitConverter uses the CPUs endianness; not a fixed endianness such as network byte order).

Comment: Technically, BitConverter has the ToChar() which allows conversion to string. Not the best approach though, I agree.

Comment: BitConverter for the Ints, and then Encoding.GetString() for the strings.  The Encoding.GetString() may need management of the nul terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer really depends on how are you converting the structure into byte array. In theory, you will need to perform the same steps in reverse sequence!

For example if you serialize the structure such that:

- first 4 bytes = no
- second 4 bytes = id
- rest bytes = byte stream of
  characters in name

then to convert the byte array back to structure, you just need to define a variable of that structure type and assign the members with values converted from byte array!

Answer (score 1):

Note that many platforms include tools for this purpose; while you *can* write custom [de]serialization code, it can get tedious very quickly.

For example, google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is a language-agnostic* mechanism for describing a wire format. You can technically get better (smaller) serialization if you do everything by hand, but it will be a lot more work...

*= c++, java, etc in the google repo - plus [lots more](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/OtherLanguages) by the community